# Get only numbers from cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I use formula to display `3 hours 7 mins` as `3,07`. However for some reason the same formula does not work on Win7 Office 2013 English version it says #VALUE. Why so and how to repair it? Maybe other formula to suite for both?

Windows 10 Office 365 European version

```
=CEILING(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("hour"; R96)); "0 hours "; "")&R96;"s";"");" min";"");" hour ";",");0,1)
```

Windows 7 Office 2013 English version

```
=CEILING(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("hour", P96)), "0 hours ", "")&P96,"s","")," min","")," hour ",","),0.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`3,7` is not a number, thus when the formula reaches this point:

```
=CEILING("3,7",0.1)
```

You will get the `#VALUE` error. You can use the following instead to make it work (notice the change):

```
=CEILING(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("hour", P96)), "0 hours ", "")&P96,"s","")," min","")," hour ","."),0.1)
                                                                                                                            ^
```

Which results in `3.7`. If you need it to be a comma, you will need a final `SUBSTITUTE`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CEILING(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("hour", P96)), "0 hours ", "")&P96,"s","")," min","")," hour ","."),0.1), ".", ",")
```

Comment: @user7202022 Calculate it as `37`, and then divide by 10?  However, what will you display for "3 hours, 10 minutes" - should you be using `3.07` for "3 hours, 7 minutes" instead?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue caused by the [Decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma) differing between different countries:  Some write "one thousand and a half" as "1,000.5", others write it as "1.000,5"

So, you need to ensure that your `","` knows when it should be `"."` instead.  The simplest way that I can think of for that is `MID(1/2,2,1)` - that is, take the middle character from a half.  Depending on your settings, this will be `0.5` (result: `"."`) or `0,5` (result: `","`)

(The `0.1` at the end *should* change itself automatically between versions, since it is an actual number - if not, then change it to `1/10` for a similar result)

```
=CEILING(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("hour"; R96)); "0 hours "; "")&R96;"s";"");" min";"");" hour ";MID(1/2,2,1));1/10)
```

Also to consider:  Your current system will write "2 hours 1 minute" as "2,1" (or "2.1" depending on the settings) - but, it will *also* write "2 hours 10 minutes" as "2,1".  Your requirements may need to be reviewed

Comment: your suggestion with 37 is good. I think it should be this way. I don't need actually it to be 3,07 or 3,7 because it can be rounded to either 3,5 or 4 and devide it by 10. Maybe I need to create a new question....