# Formula to convert hours mins to number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I use formula to display `3 hours 7 mins` as `3,7`. However formula does not work correctly as it should be `3,07` also the are problems with `,` and `.` depending on Excel version.

I don't need it to be 3,07 or 3,7. I need formula to round it to either 3,5 or 4. So if it is 3,07 then it should be 3,5. Basically condition is if `mins` or `min` is less than 30 then it is `,5` if more than 30 then next `,0`. Then this formula should give as a result 35 and divide it by 10. So for example 35/10 or 40/10. Then there will be no problem with `,` and `.` in different Excel versions.

NOTE! Value in `P96` comes from Google Maps API xml and shows travelling hours from one location to another. Sometimes there is `3 hours 7 mins`, `20 hours 37 mins` and sometimes `1 hour 1 min`

Current solution:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CEILING(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("hour", P96)), "0 hours ", "")&P96,"s","")," min","")," hour ","."),0.1), ".", ",")
```

Comment: what is value in cell `P96`

Comment: @PraveenDA Sometimes there is `3 hours 7 mins`, `20 hours 37 mins` and sometimes `1 hour 1 min`

Comment: See this possible duplicate or **very** similar : https://stackoverflow.com/q/56017220/4961700

Comment: Yes, but it was originally related to another issue that has been solved and now I came up with another problem with `.` and `,` So I created another question. This is also about rounding up values that was not in the previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
=IF(VALUE(IF(FIND("min",A2,1)=11,MID(A2,FIND("min",A2,1)-2,1),MID(A2,FIND("min",A2,1)-3,2)))<30, VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND("hour",A2,1)-2)) & "." &  5,VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND("hour",A2,1)-2))+1)
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If there is always a space before and after each number, try this:

```
=LEFT(P96,2)+LOOKUP(--MID(P96,FIND("min",P96)-3,3),{1,30},{0.5,1})
```

It means that 1 to 29 min are transformed to 0.5, and >=30 to 1.